# override sync function which is in BelongsToMany || laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel, pivot, overriding, relation

I need to override the sync function which is in BelongsToMany inside the InteractsWithPivotTable Trait

becuse I want to add scope when detaching

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class TableName extends Model
{

    // number 1
    /**
     * Sync the intermediate tables with a list of IDs or collection of models.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Support\Collection|\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|array  $ids
     * @param  bool  $detaching
     * @return array
     */
    public function sync($ids, $detaching = true, callable $wherePivot = null)
    {
    }

    // number 2
    public function syncWhere($ids, callable $wherePivot = null)
    {
        // Custom logic here
        // You can modify or add additional functionality

        // Call the parent sync method to perform the default sync behavior
        return parent::sync($ids, false);
    }
}
```

but those doesn't work because the sync function is not in the Model class

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that I have to extend the BelongsToMany Relation Class then override inside it then use it instead of the origin BelognsToMany Class